# Sending information from image uploader to the model carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

So currently i have my table with a width column and a height column,

```
def store_dimensions
if file && model
  model.width, model.height = ::MiniMagick::Image.open(file.file[:dimensions])
 end
end
```

I use this method to set the height and width so when in validation methods in the model i can validate that the dimensions are valid.

I wondering if there was a better way to send params over to the model instead of persisting them to the database because after validation they arent used again.

Ive tried to add

`attr_accessor :height, width`

to the uploader and the model then setting the variables in store dimensions method but cant retrieve them on the model end.

If anyone has had any experience doing this could you shed some light thanks

Comment: You can keep your current code and add `attr_accessor :height, :width` in the model. Since you are doing validation on model side, you would need height and width available there, but you do not need to persist them in database if you do not want to.

Comment: @rubish Hello rubish!  Thankyou for  replying! thats worked... My only question is how come i dont need to put the attr_accessor in the uploader as thats where the height and width are set? and its read in the model?

Comment: @rubish can you answer the question so i mark it answered please too

Comment: Have posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use some fields only for validations, one can define attr_accessor on the model, but need to keep in mind that these attributes would only be available when assigned explicitly(since not backed by DB columns).

For current scenario, you can keep your current code and define `attr_accessor :height, :width` on the model and use them in validations.